# OS X Install – Problems With PIL

Tags: ros, installation, rosdep, ros-hydro, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to install Hydro on a fresh OS X Mavericks system, but I get hung up during the following command:

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro hydro -y
```

The issue I'm getting is with PIL: `Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement PIL`. When I try to install PIL manually (using `sudo pip install -U PIL --allow-external PIL --allow-unverified PIL`), I get stuck at `_imagingft.c:73:10: fatal error: 'freetype/fterrors.h' file not found`, even though freetype is installed and up to date.

Has anyone else experienced the same issue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/115781/os-x-install-%E2%80%93-problems-with-pil/) by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 539 on 2014-01-07

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on 2014-01-08**:
Worked perfectly! Feel free to copy/paste my answer so I can give you sweet, sweet karma =)

**Comment by [lanyusea](https://answers.ros.org/users/10266/lanyusea/) on 2014-01-08**:
@nckswt, done. as a newbie I'm not sure whether it should be a comment or answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

can that help?
`ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.5.1/include/freetype2 /usr/local/include/freetype`

reference:
stackoverflow.com/questions/20325473/error-installing-python-image-library-using-pip-on-mac-os-x-10-9

---

Originally posted by [lanyusea](https://answers.ros.org/users/10266/lanyusea/) with karma: 279 on 2014-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-01-20**:
Note that if you later decide to install ogre with `brew install ogre`, you might need to remove that symlink again for it to compile (at least when I did this a while back it was neccessary).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're having issues with installing PIP during the dependencies install, you need to symlink it:

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.5.2/include/freetype2 /usr/local/include/freetype
```

Don't forget to tab-complete to make sure your version number is accurate. After that, you can manually install pip, then continue with the dependency install:

```
sudo pip install -U PIL --allow-external PIL --allow-unverified PIL 
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro hydro -y
```

[Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20325473/error-installing-python-image-library-using-pip-on-mac-os-x-10-9)

---

Originally posted by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) with karma: 539 on 2014-01-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1